# Добавить класс на JS нужному div при выборе нужного option

Tags: javascript

Вот разметка:

```
<select name="" id="select-vip-option" class="vip__select">
    <option class="vip__option" value="01">Мобильный агент</option>
    <option class="vip__option" value="02">VIP-залы</option>
    <option class="vip__option" value="03">Fast-track</option>
    <option class="vip__option" value="04">VIP-трансфер</option>
    <option class="vip__option" value="05">Консьерж сервис</option>
</select>


<div class="vip__info" id="tab-vip-mobile-agent"></div>
<div class="vip__info display-none" id="tab-vip-mobile-agent"></div>
<div class="vip__info display-none" id="tab-vip-mobile-agent"></div>
<div class="vip__info display-none" id="tab-vip-mobile-agent"></div>
<div class="vip__info display-none" id="tab-vip-mobile-agent"></div>
```

при выборе нужного option нужно убрать класс display-none у определенного div и добавить ко всем остальным
И если с кнопками я еще понимаю как это сделать, то с option вообще не могу осознать. 
Те с какой стороны вообще подступить к этому вопросу? пожалуйста подскажите на пальцах

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так, например:

```js
let o = document.querySelector('#select-vip-option');
o.onchange = function() {
  [...document.querySelectorAll('.vip__info')].forEach((el, i) => {
     el.classList.toggle('display-none', o.value != i + 1);
  });
}
```

```css
.vip__info{
  border:1px solid red;
}

.display-none{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<select name="" id="select-vip-option" class="vip__select">
    <option class="vip__option" value="01">Мобильный агент</option>
    <option class="vip__option" value="02">VIP-залы</option>
    <option class="vip__option" value="03">Fast-track</option>
    <option class="vip__option" value="04">VIP-трансфер</option>
    <option class="vip__option" value="05">Консьерж сервис</option>
</select>


<div class="vip__info" id="tab-vip-mobile-agent">0</div>
<div class="vip__info display-none" id="tab-vip-mobile-agent">1</div>
<div class="vip__info display-none" id="tab-vip-mobile-agent">2</div>
<div class="vip__info display-none" id="tab-vip-mobile-agent">3</div>
<div class="vip__info display-none" id="tab-vip-mobile-agent">4</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select onchange="optionChanged(this)" ...

function optionChanged(select) {
  var selected = +select.value;
  document.querySelectorAll(".vip__info").forEach((el, i) => {
    if (i + 1 == selected)
      e.classList.remove("display-none");
    else
      e.classList.add("display-none");
  });
}
```